# How to build a custom accuracy metric with tolerance in TF2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, customization, metrics

I want to build a custom accuracy metric with tolerance. Instead of counting elements exactly equal in `y_true` and `y_pred`, this accuracy regards the two elements are consistent if their difference within a given tolerance value. For example, if the differences between predicted degrees and true degrees are smaller than 5 degree, we can think the results are correct and calculate the accuracy based on this rule. I want to use this metric in `model.compile` so it should be a callable function.

I wrote a function as follows.

```
def accuracy_with_tolerence(y_true,y_pred):
    """
    y_true/y_pred: batch of samples; (BatchSize, 1)
    """
    threshold = 5
    differnece = tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true,y_pred)) - threshold
    boolean_results = [True if i < 0 else False for i in differnece]
    return K.mean(math_ops.cast(boolean_results, K.floatx()))
```

It can return the correct accuracy value.

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant([5, 8, 10], dtype=tf.float32)
acc = accuracy_with_tolerence(x,y)
print(acc)
```

```
tf.Tensor(0.33333334, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

But when I want to use it in compile, there is an error:

```
# Initialize ResNet50
model = resnet50()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse',metrics=[accuracy_with_tolerence])
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath_0)
model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
```

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

It seems I cannot iterate the Tensor. So how can I get element-wise boolean comparison results in the metric function? How can I realize this accuracy function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but why not just use the MSE itself? Your metric will be as biased as MSE is but less accurate due to the thresholding.

Comment: Actually, this is in a steering angle control scenario, which is a practical regression problem. MSE can be used as a metric but people cannot get a general level of performance from it directly(all floating numbers anyway). Accuracy metric is more intuitive in comparison to MSE. If vehicles can be very close to ground truth behavior(within the tolerance) most of time, they will self-drive smoothly and safely.

Comment: It's indeed more intuitive for non-tech people (though it might be obscuring important  underlying relationships), just be careful when binning/thresholding like this. It's impossible to choose the ideal threshold for evaluation and it might simplify your results so much that you lose robustness in model interpretation and could as a result skew your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a list comprehension with a tensor. The operation you're looking for is [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) and you can use it as follows:

```
def accuracy_with_tolerence(y_true, y_pred):
    threshold = 5
    differnece = tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)) - threshold
    boolean_results = tf.where(differnece>0, True, False)
    return K.mean(math_ops.cast(boolean_results, K.floatx()))
```

Note that you can simplify the code further:

```
    ...
    boolean_results = tf.where(tf.abs(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)) - threshold>0, 1., 0.)
    return K.mean(boolean_results)
```

Comment: That works! That is exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you so much~ Learned a lot from your answer.